# Каким образом отключить вывод файлов при index of

Tags: php, .htaccess

Здравствуйте. На сайте есть папки в которых нет файла главной страницы, и например если ввести в url эту папку и перейти в нее, пишет Idex of и при этом выводит все системные файлы и папки.

Каким образом этого избежать?
Буду благодарен за помощью.

Answer (score 2):

Нашел решение. 
в .htaccess :

```
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteEngine On                     #Включаем движок
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  #Запрещаем вывод папок
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f #Запрещаем вывод файлов, если вам это тоже нужно удалите знак # вначале строки
```

Добавьте код в файл .htaccess

Comment: Почему это условие `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` у вас запрещает вывод папок?